# Avoid image scaling in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-imageview, android-view

I am using an Image view with these XML attributes

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_list_bitmap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/place_holder" >
</ImageView>
```

and at runtime I create a let's say 400x400 bitmap, save it to a file and set the ImageView src using a file URI

remoteViews.setUri(R.id.widget_list_bitmap, "setImageURI", myFileUri);

(this is to avoid RemoteViews issues with large bitmaps).

Everything works fine except that the displayed image is scaled down and is smaller than 400x400, more like 250 x 250 (possibly 400/density, density = 1.5).

Is there a way to force an ImageView to really not scaling images it fetches from URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually download it and when you load it with `BitmapFactory` set [`inScaled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled) to false. Then you would use [`setImageViewBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap%28int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) instead of `setUri` or [`setImageViewUri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewUri%28int,%20android.net.Uri%29).

**Update:**

Unfortunately I don't really see a way around this using `setUri`. An alternative to using `setUri` to get around the 1MB limit is to use `setImageViewBitmap` but slice up the bitmap and display it on multiple views, maybe a 2x2 or 3x3 grid of ImageViews or something like that. You'd have to split it into multiple updates using [`partiallyUpdateAppWidget`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#partiallyUpdateAppWidget%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29), but I think it should work. The hitch is that this requires API 11.

Comment: RemoteViews has issues with large bitmaps. This is why I went the URI route. You can find more info here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/discussion

Comment: Updated with another possible solution to the 1MB limit.

Comment: Not a direct answer to my question but solves my underlying problem so marking it as a solution (should I edit the title?). The slicing seems to work (using 3 ImageViews in a vertical LinearLayout). Currently I am doing three regular updates. Was not aware of partiallyUpdateAppWidget, will take a look give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Update: partiallyUpdateAppWidget is available from API 11 only (I am using 8). The slicing using updateAppWidget() does work but once in 20 updates or so I still get a binding error. Try to issue System.gc() after updating each image slice which makes things better but still not 100% reliable. Still looking for a solution how to avoid the ImageView scaling with setUri.

Comment: Also found this discussion, in case somebody is interested. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/discussion